# JQuery Incremental Search

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a JQuery plugin that will assist in an incremental search e.g. - the user starts typing into a textbox and an AJAX call is made to dynamically get results as the user types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [this plugin](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm) maybe.

Answer (score 3):

Just googled - [Autocomplete](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/).

Comment: Shame that link isn't the resulting Google page.

Answer (score 0):

I've used jQuery Autocomplete successfully in the past: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. The AJAX part will depend on your specific implementation.